# Will the segments be the same in case of Google Play app updates?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, updates, mobile-application

the Google Play Store allows to update app with segmentation.

For example v1.1 update to 10% of v1 users (for example 1.000 users of all 10.000 users). After it if we update v1.1 to v1.2, with 10% segmentation, the previous 10% segment will get the new update also? If I think consequently, the segment will stay the same and no other segment will be created. Is it true? So the same 10% segment will get the further updates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you halt a staged rollout, or create a new release in do a staged rollout of that release before your original release halts, then the update will go to the same population of users. This lets you fix users that you broke with a bad release.

The instructions and documentation for Staged rollouts are all [here on the help center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149).

However, at the moment the documentation around this point is not very good (it basically doesn't say anything). I've spoken to the team and they will try and get the documentation improved. Sorry about that.